# Trying to id a font

Tags: fonts, font-identification

This font was created using Adobe CS4 and I am using Corel Draw 6. I cannot id this font and need to do so to create more graphics using it.

What is this font?:

[image]

Comment: You might want to check this out http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info

Comment: Mike, if you have bigger image of that same text, it would help a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The letters are the most distinctive element of this font; that serif on the 7 isn't too common. Also, when looking, keep an eye out for the 'K' in particular, since the diagonals don't always cross like that.

I scanned through MyFonts' sans-serif list and found [Houschka Pro Medium](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/g-type/houschka-alt-pro/):

[image: Houschka Alt Pro Medium]

I don't know if it's a perfect fit (the size and tracking on your example are throwing me off a bit) but if not it's *very* close.

Answer (score 0):

[Tikal Sans Medium](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/latinotype/tikal-sans/medium/) looks close to this font and the numeric is different font [Pepperell Braiding](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/btn/revelation-btn/regular/) Hemp look close

[image]